# Overflow scroll on scaled child: different behavior on X and Y axis

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Here is a code showing my issue

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  /* When scaling down, no more X scrolling because size is 200px, but still Y scrolling :( */
  transform: scale(0.5);
  /* Both axis working the same (no more scrolling) when absolutely positioned */
  /* position: absolute; */
}

/* Irrelevant styling */
.container {
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: pink;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>

Try to scroll down or right within the box.
```

- There is a container with a fixed size, containing a child also with a fixed size.
- There is overflow scrolling.
- Then I scale down the child with a transformation, halving its size.

  - The X scroll disappears because child's width is 200px (more specifically, container's scrollWidth property has shrinked accordingly)
  - The Y scroll is still there and the container's scrollHeight property is still the same.

I can somewhat understand the behavior of each axis, but not why **they're acting differently**.

Ideally I'd like the Y axis to act like the X axis.

If I set `position:absolute` on the child, then the Y axis acts as the X axis (**Both scrolls disappears**).

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position:absolute;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

/* Irrelevant styling */
.container {
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: pink;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>

Try to scroll down or right within the box.
```

Same thing when I set `display:inline-block`. Both axis behave the sames (**Both scrolls aren't affected by scale**)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display:inline-block;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

/* Irrelevant styling */
.container {
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: pink;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>

Try to scroll down or right within the box.
```

Why in the initial case, we have a different behavior? And why in some cases, the scale change the scroll (when we used `position:absolute`) and in other cases it doesn't (when we used `display:inline-block`).

---

As a side note, `transform` is a visual effect that doesn't affect the layout so logically the scroll shouldn't change in all the cases.

Comment: here is another one: make the child element inline-block and the scroll will not change at all

Comment: Hehe nice find :)

Comment: I edited the question to add more details ;) let's hope it will attract more attention

Comment: Thanks :) I forgot to mention it's working as intended on Edge (scrolling is never affected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a few confusing statements in [w3.org website](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scrollable) about scollable overflow that might explain why the implementation is inconsistent. They look more like TODO marks, since it's a draft:

ISSUE 1:

> There’s disagreement on the scrolling model. 2.1 apparently defined
>   that you scrolled the *content* area; the content would overflow the
>   content-box, and you would union that overflow with the content box to
>   find the scrollable area. In particular, this means that the content
>   would be offset by the start-sides padding, but if it overflowed, it
>   would go right to the edge on the end sides. This is what Firefox and
>   IE do. At least some authors (and spec authors) instead have the
>   mental model that the padding box is what’s scrollable, so when you
>   scroll to the end of the overflow, there’s the right/bottom padding.
>   Chrome/WebKit do this for the block axis, at least. They’re somewhat
>   inconsistent for the inline axis; there’s something weird about how
>   they handle lineboxes.
>
> It seems that the block-axis padding is probably web-compatible to
>   honor. It’s unclear that the inline-axis padding will be. Further
>   experimentation is needed.

ISSUE 2:

> Is this description of handling transforms sufficiently accurate?

Note:

> The scrollable overflow rectangle is always a rectangle in the
>   box’s own coordinate system, but might be non-rectangular in other
>   coordinate systems due to transforms [CSS3-TRANSFORMS]. This means
>   scrollbars can sometimes appear when not actually necessary.

Anyway, it seems that we need to rely on "position:absolute" as a workaround for Chrome. Or transform the container instead of the child. Or even create an extra cointainer level.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The first issue seems only about padding, not about transforms. The second issue needs a little context. Could you please elaborate on that? The note seems only applicable on other coordinate systems and not on this question.

Comment: Issue 1 refers to padding as it is described by w3c's "scrollable overflow" definition: "The scrollable overflow of a box is the set of things extending outside of that box’s padding edge for which a scrolling mechanism needs to be provided."

Comment: Issue 2 refers to part of the scrollable overflow region: "the border boxes of all boxes for which it is the containing block and whose border boxes are positioned not wholly outside its block-start or inline-start padding edges, accounting for transforms by projecting each box onto the plane of the element that establishes its 3D rendering context."

Comment: In general, I'm trying to point references proving that there's no solid definition for transformation behavior inside scrollable overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the discrepancy in behaviour is linked to the transform-origin. When the origin is adjusted so that the child is placed to the right rather than the left (and the inline-block display removed), the horizontal scroll reappears and the child is only visible on scroll-over (see code snippet). As the child's [default 'static' position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) (even without being transformed) would display from the top of the container, this is why it doesn't affect the vertical scroll in the same manner as I understand it.

As others have pointed out, there are outstanding tasks regarding CSS transforms. I would't regard it as a bug (although I see your point). Perhaps better explanations/more clarity will become available in future from the w3c.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  background-color: pink;
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>

Transform-origin changed to top right (as opposed to top left)
```